# Clearing IAP test user history from device

Tags: ios, testing, ios7, in-app-purchase

As the title suggests, I am testing my app's IAP on my devices. I have set up a few test user accounts and I want to test some scenarios out and for that, I need to delete the history of a previous test user on a device.

For this, I sign out of one ID in Settings and run my app, but even then, the app displays a dialog asking me to enter the password for the old one. This happens even when I have not started any IAP related activity on the app. I am frankly quite annoyed by this and I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue before, which was related to a previous purchase not having been completed (due to a bug in my handling of the transaction), so every time I launched the app, storekit would forward the app the unfinished transaction, which would prompt for login again

see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html

the pertinent section: (emphasis added)

> Register a transaction queue observer when your app is launched, as
>   shown in Listing 4-1. Make sure that the observer is ready to handle a
>   transaction at any time, not just after you add a transaction to the
>   queue. For example, consider the case of a user buying something in
>   your app right before going into a tunnel. Your app isn’t able to
>   deliver the purchased content because there’s no network connection.
>   The next time your app is launched, Store Kit calls your transaction
>   queue observer again and delivers the purchased content at that time.
>   **Similarly, if your app fails to mark a transaction as finished, Store
>   Kit calls the observer every time your app is launched until the
>   transaction is properly finished**

So you may need to add a handler to handle the transaction, then it will go away! (probably)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will definitely try this.

Comment: I think it's also possible that after a long enough period of time, the transaction may time out, but from my slightly hazy memory it was quite a long period of time!

Comment: Hmm. That is a possibility. I should double check my implementation and make sure that I am completing the transactions right.

Comment: Hey. I know it has been a while. But, can you suggest a way I can set up a handler for this case? As in, how can I catch the events when StoreKit forwards an unfinished transaction?

Comment: Make sure you have an observer set-up (somewhere like in your appDelegate so it gets called on startup) then implement the - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions method, and you should get notified in there of any pending transactions. In the observer, you can call - (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction on any transactions that are forwarded, if you don't actually care about completing them/retrying/notifying the user etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried this, and most of the incomplete ones have been set as finished. But there is one transaction, that is stuck, whose state is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing. I am not able to mark is as finished. The app crashed with the message - "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot finish a purchasing transaction'". Any idea how I can handle this case?

Comment: You can't call "finishTransaction on a transaction that's purchasing, as that's happening at the app-store end. You need the observer to hang around long enough for the state to change to completed/failed so that you can call the finishTransaction: method on it. Otherwise, the transaction will return after the observer has gone, and the finishTransaction will never gets called. If it doesn't ever come back  from that state I'm out of ideas on what to suggest! :/

Comment: Ah. That's probably what's happening. A bunch of my past transactions seem to be stuck in this state and I have no idea how to handle them. :(